# how to return double datatype inside a function with 4 decimal places?

Tags: java, function, double, decimal

How to return double datatype with 4 decimals in a function in java ?

```
    public static double fun(){
    double d=2.5d;
    String s=String.format("%.4f",d);
    double ans=Double.parseDouble(s);
    return(ans); }
```

actual output=2.5
expected output=2.5000

Comment: You can not adjust precision for the double value itself rather than you can set precision for the output format of the String representation of the value. Cheers.

Comment: why not return the double and then process it to 4 decimal points ?
Otherwise, you could return a string that has 4 digit characters after a decimal point

Comment: If you want to have a specific representation then you can no longer use a double since a double has a specific value, it does not care about how it will be displayed. The only option would be to return a `String` representation of the double. Just `return s`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: You can also just return it as an `int` multiplied by `10000` (shifting the decimal point 4 digits to the right): `return (int) Math.round(d * 10000);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the double for mathematical computation, using `2.5` is equivalent to `2.5000`. Can you be more specific as to why you would want the latter?

If you really do need the 4 decimal places, I assume it is some sort of output formatting task, in which case you can just return the String representation directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Well, Its the question i got in my exam.The problem is function return data type is double and that also needs to be give upto 4 decimal places.

Comment: I think the key word here is 'upto'. So they probably mean having a max of 4 decimal places. So anything that has a greater precision than 4 would be rounded off to 4 decimal places. And anything less than 4 would stay as it is.

Comment: Here is a way to round it off to 4 decimal places 

`BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleVal)).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
return bd.doubleValue();`

You can also do this -> 

`(double) Math.round(doubleVal * 10000d) / 10000d`

But the second option is likely to produce rounding errors so I would recommend the first.